# Swift возвращать в функции такой же тип, который вошёл

Tags: массивы, swift, double, int

Функция может принимать массив [int] или [double].
Она должна вернуть результат в таком же типе в котором приняла. 
Как этого легче всего добиться? Есть ли в Swift некая "перегрузка параметров функции"?

Comment: перегрузка-то есть, но не уверен что вам нужна именно она, а не шаблоны. Опишите свою задачу поподробнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотел продолжить в комментариях, но там уж очень неудобно с кодом будет. В целом вашу задачу - вычисление среднего того же типа - действительно можно решить простой перегрузкой, написав отдельные функции для каждого из интересующего вас типов:

```
func average(_ T: [Double]) -> Double {
    return T.reduce(0.0) {$0+$1} / Double(T.count)
}

func average(_ T: [Int]) -> Int {
    return T.reduce(0) {$0+$1} / T.count
}

print(average([1,2,3]))
print(average([0.1,1.1,2.2]))
```

но у такого решения есть один существенный минус - оно работает только для тех типов что вы определили т.е. если вам понадобится взять среднее не просто от Int, а от UInt или Int8 - вам придется писать новую функцию именно с этим типом. В то же время в Свифте есть еще такая интересная штука как темплейты когда вы задаете нечто абстрактное, а компиллятор уже сам смотрит что используется в коде и генерит соотвествующие методы-типы и так далее. Код будет вот таким:

```
func averageTemplate<T:BinaryInteger>(_ tt:[T])->T{
    let s = tt.reduce(0) {$0+$1}
    return s/T(tt.count)
}

func averageTemplate<T:FloatingPoint>(_ tt:[T])->T{
    let s = tt.reduce(0) {$0+$1}
    return s/T(tt.count)
}
print(averageTemplate([1,2,3]))
print(averageTemplate([0.1,1.1,2.2]))
let t = [0, 1, 2].map{UInt16($0)}
print(averageTemplate(t))
```

Совсем отказаться от перегрузки я, как видите, не смог (потому что инит из инта для целых и для вещественных в Свифте определен в разных протоколах), но тем не менее написаные таким образом методы работают с любым типом поддерживающим эти протоколы и писать дополнительный код для UInt и компании уже не нужно.
Разумеется, код приведен для примера и не описывает все случаи (например, получение пустого массива его завалит), но, думаю, общую суть он иллюстрирует неплохо.